# How to include(and display) multiple-page PDF in R-Markdown html file?

Tags: html, r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

I'm looking for a solutions such as this one:

```
\includegraphics[page=2]{myFirstAlignment2.pdf}
```

However, this only works for PDF Markdown, and I need to create html file.

How can I display all of the pdf pages?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it. It creates a button that when hit, opens the PDF. And you can scroll down through all the slides.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Spectra">Open Absortion Spectra Slides</button> 
<div id="Spectra" class="collapse">    
<object data="IRSpectra.pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
    <embed src="IRSpectra.pdf">
    </embed>
</object>
</div>
```

If you only wanted the slides (without the button), you'd just need this:

```
<object data="IRSpectra.pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
    <embed src="IRSpectra.pdf">
    </embed>
</object>
```